# Validation.error event in event command

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, binding, eventtocommand

I have a text box:

```
    <TextBox Height="20" Width="150" Text="{Binding MyProperty,NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" >
          <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="Validation.Error">
                <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MyCmd}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" ></mvvm:EventToCommand>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
  public class MyViewModel : ValidationViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int myVar;

    [Range(0, 10)]
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set
        {
            myVar = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }



    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyCmd = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(Valid);
    }

    public RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> MyCmd { get; set; }

    private void Valid(RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        //Do something
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

When I catch the event Validation.Error in Code Behind it works:

[image]

But when I try to run it this way with the Event Command is not coming Valid function.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Validation.Error` is **Attached Event**, then it does not work with `EventToCommand` normally.

The answer you will find at the link below:

**[EventToCommand with attached event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401082/eventtocommand-with-attached-event/17401937?noredirect=1#17401937)**

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Validation.Error` event for [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox_events.aspx). Furthermore, there is no `Validating` event for `System.Controls.TextBox` (which you are using).

Use `LostFocus` to validate the textbox or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884595/wpf-mvvm-error-validation) if you want to use Validation with MVVM pattern

Comment: Indeed, there are Validation.Error to a text box. Look at the picture in question. It works in Code Behind. I'm not interested in Lost focus - validation is already working. I want to run command when the validation error occurred.

Comment: No, there is no `Validation.Error` *event* for `TextBox`. You are trying to use it as *event*, which is wrong.

Comment: When this in Code Behind - this is not an event?

Comment: Validation.Error Attached Event : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.error(v=vs.100).aspx