# EventToCommand with attached event

Tags: wpf, events, binding, eventtocommand

I use on attached event `Validation.Error` of the TextBox.

**[Validation.Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.error%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

I want to bind it to `EventToCommand`.

Normally it does not work:

```
 <TextBox Height="20" Width="150" Text="{Binding MyProperty,NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" ><!--Validation.Error="TextBox_Error"-->
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Validation.Error">
           <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MyCmd}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" ></mvvm:EventToCommand>
        </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </TextBox>
```

So I found a way to do it, you can see it at the link below:

**[Attached an mvvm event to command to an attached event](http://sergecalderara.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/how-to-attached-an-mvvm-eventtocommand-to-an-attached-event/)**

But I get an error:

```
RoutedEventConverter cannot convert from System.String.
```

[image]

Can anyone help?

**EDIT :**

My command in the `ViewModel`

```
  public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyCmd = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(Valid);
    }

    public RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> MyCmd { get; set; }

    private void Valid(RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

Comment: What is the definition of your ViemModel "MyCmd" Command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basing it on the link you posted,

The class `RoutedEventTrigger` expects a `RoutedEvent` and your xaml is not able to convert the string `Validation.Error` to the required type.

so switch

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <view_model:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="Validation.Error">
    <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MyCmd}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
  </view_model:RoutedEventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

to

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <view_model:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="{x:Static Validation.ErrorEvent}">
    <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MyCmd}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
  </view_model:RoutedEventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and it should be fine

Comment: What is view_model: ??

Comment: @AllanRuin just the namespace where the `RoutedEventTrigger` class from the linked article from the OP post is declared.