# Return Focus to WPF Element when contents fail validation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am validating the data entered in a TextBox when it looses the Focus.
When my validation rule identifies the contents of a TextBox as invalid I would like to automatically return the Focus back to the TextBox.
My reasoning is that if the user has to reenter valid data I can save him a keystroke by prepositioning the cursor for them.

I pass the name of the TextBox through to the validation class like so ...

```
<TextBox x:Name="addAnInteger">
<Binding.ValidationRules>                                            
     <local:ValidateInteger32 TextBoxName="addAnInteger"/>                                                     
</Binding.ValidationRules>
</TextBox>
```

In the validation class (ValidateInteger32) I have:

```
public string TextBoxName { get; set; }
```

The property TextBoxName receives and stores the name of the TextBox that I want to reset the Focus to.

How can I set the Focus back to the "addAnInteger" TextBox from inside the ValidateInteger32 validation class using only the name of the property TextBoxName? I'm thinking something like ....

```
[Commands that expose the contents of TextBoxName].Focus();
```

I don't want to use the name of individual TextBoxes in the validation class because I want the class to be generic.

Grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Validation.Error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.error(v=vs.110).aspx) event. you will get Instance there.

take a look at this: [Validation.error event in event command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399708/validation-error-event-in-event-command)

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

The `ValidationRule` simply returns a `ValidationResult`. It has doesn't know anything about the `TextBox` in the view.

It is the responsibility of the control/view itself to act on the validation result. You could for example handle the `Validation.Error` event like this:

```
private void addAnInteger_Error(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { Keyboard.Focus(textBox); }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="addAnInteger" Margin="10" Validation.Error="addAnInteger_Error">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Text" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:ValidateInteger32 />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Or you will have to bind the a reference to the actual `TextBox` to the `ValidationRule` somehow. Please refer to my answer here for more information about this:

[How to bind values from xaml to validation rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519802/how-to-bind-values-from-xaml-to-validation-rule/46523657#46523657)